# C# mousedown event continously press key

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys, mousedown

okay so what I want to do, it when the mouse is HELD DOWN I want it to continously press a key. it should continously press this key until I let off.

Imagine if you will, a left and right button on a windows form, 
then by clicking and holding the right button, the letter "R" displays on a textbox continously until you release the button.  What I am doing has very little to do with that scenario, but you get what I'm trying to do here.

What exactly do I put in the mouse down to keep the sendkeys going forever without locking up the application?

I hope my question makes sense. lol.

Thanks

RT

```
private void pictureBoxKeyboard_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
//something goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worth a read...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

SendKeys.Send("r")

This might just fire once, you may want to attach a timer that starts on the MouseDown event and stops on the MouseUp event.  Then you could put the SendKeys in the Timer.Tick event.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Interval = 500;
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs  e) 
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        this.Text = "moose-Up";
    }

    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        this.Text = "moose-Down";
        this.richTextBox1.Select();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("r");
        Debug.Print("tickling");
    }
```

Select the control that you wish to receive the SendKeys value...

Comment: i'm glad this was helpful... also, if you wanted to you could put a local var into the class to reflect what key should be pressed, should you have more than one button...  just set the var during the mouse-down event of the button, then consume the var during the Tick() event.